# Web application to send email alerts

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, smtp

I have developed an application that checks some values from the database and send email alerts to the specific user. When I upload the war file on tomcat it works fine but the next day it stops sending emails. And then when I restart "Servlet Server (Tomcat)" service it works fine again. or if I undeploy and then deploy again it works fine. I have other applications running on the same server that collects the data from the sensors continuously, they are fine. But this is the only application that send email to the users.
So any guess, what is wrong going on here.

Can there be any configuration issue with the email Account I am sending the emails from?
I set the Mailbox quota to unlimited!!

Remember: Application is working fine, but I have to restart tomcat server daily!!!!

Comment: How many emails your application send? Maybe the account server marks your mail like SPAM?

Comment: It can send multiple emails.... but for one day I have received about 50-60 emails. What happens on the next day and when I start tomcat again it works....???

Comment: It can stop working if you don't release your DB resources after you have checked your data. You may be getting a DoS this way.

Comment: That is true, I was not releasing the database resources, but can this really be a problem?? I am doing the same for other applications that collects data from the sensors and upload into the database :).... But that is good point anyway.

Comment: Do you have some kind of background thread that checks values from database ?

Comment: My tip would be your app never reaches the part where it is trying to send the email because of some other error (DB connection, whatever else). Do you have some logging in place to check the app is really calling the send mail?

Comment: well... as I wrote in the question.. My application works fine... It gets the values from the database, it sends email, I receive emails but just for 1 day only, the next day I do not receive any email....

OK let me put it this way....

Comment: A user selects the daily email time which I save into the database.... This application reads the time from the database and if the time matches it sends the email... So my application checks the database every minute and compare the email time with current time.... And this works fine but for one day... Next day I dont receive any email...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to do lots of investigation on this issue. I suggest you turn on your logging feature on you app and try to get as detail information as possible in your log file. Then you can figure out what is going on. It might be a bottle-neck in the system that you have to sit on it for a while to throw exceptions.